# How to use "grommet" without node.js?

Tags: reactjs, grommet

I heard "grommet with reactjs" has good UI. So I want to try "grommet" on my environment. But I couldn't understand how to use "grommet". Because I expected this module can work on usual internet browser only. But sometime some websites explained "to use node.js" for grommet. Is this serverside module? Can't use "grommet" internet browser only?

https://v2.grommet.io/

I already read component's page but I wasn't able to understand.
https://v2.grommet.io/components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is a framework for creating UI components.

Grommet is a set of components built with React. If you need a calendar in your application, you can use the calendar provided by Grommet instead of building your own.

Another example of a component library similar to Grommet is [Blueprint](https://blueprintjs.com).

You can use Grommet wherever you use React. React is meant to be displayed in a browser. React can also be rendered server-side (into static HTML) and then made 'dynamic' again on the client (browser side).

React is javascript, and if you want to see React in a browser, the browser needs to fetch the javascript and HTML from the website from a server/website. You can, but do not have to, use Node.js to serve your React/Grommet website.

Comment: Thank you for reply quickly. Hm... "grommet with react" can use client side only but also it with server side. Is this correct? I saw some samples on the internet but they always need to setup with "node.js". Do you know where is the examples of "grommet" client side only? my question might not be proper for you. I'm sorry I 'm not familiar this technologies. I'm trying to get now.

Comment: OK I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ichiro Examples of Grommet on the client side are available on the Grommet web site. Go to the components page and you can look at every component. You can even click on any component and then click on "CodeSandbox" and it will bring you to a page where you can experiment. Good luck

Comment: Hello I investigated all of information as much as possible on the internet. However, I wasn't able to find the good information for running "grommet" without node.js(it's means running grommet on the internet browser only). I might give up but I decided to post last question for you. I found also this official information below.
https://v1.grommet.io/docs/setup/

I expect "node.js" might be mandatory to run "grommet". Is this correct?

Comment: Did you complete the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) that I linked to? The [Setup for the Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-for-the-tutorial) section, specifically, explains your options for running React in the browser. You can also run any Grommet component in CodeSandbox, using the link from Grommet's website, as explained above. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/grommet/grommet-sandbox?initialpath=rangeselector&module=%2Fsrc%2FRangeSelector.js) is an example of one such sandbox. Hope that helps

Comment: My earlier comment with the link to the react tutorial seems to have disappeared, not sure how/why

Comment: Yes... I already saw the sandbox. I understood this logic also. But can this code run on the browser only? [import SandboxComponent from './SandboxComponent';] I couldn't understand how to set up this environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197843/discussion-between-ichiro-and-code-bling).

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for your support!!

Comment: You can upvote the answer if it helped answer the question